# Change background of some CalendarItem item in Lift/Scala

Tags: jquery, css, scala, lift

I'm trying use Lift and CalendarMonthView widget to build a
appointment system.

CalendarMonthView works with Lift very well, but I have a problem that
could not change the style of some CalendarItem that displayed on the
calendar.

According to the API document, I use the following code to change the
css class of certain CalendarItem when build the calendar.

```
class MySnippet {
    def test (xhtml: NodeSeq) = {
        val c    = Calendar.getInstance
        val meta = MonthViewMeta (Calendar.SUNDAY, Locale.getDefault)

        c.set (2010, 0, 0)

        bind ("cal", xhtml, 
              "widget" -> CalendarMonthView (c, meta, cals, Empty, 
                                             Empty, Empty))
    }

    def cals = {
        val c1 = Calendar.getInstance
        val c2 = Calendar.getInstance

        c1.set (2010, 0, 5, 10, 0)
        c2.set (2010, 0, 6, 10, 0)

        val calitem1 = CalendarItem ("4", c1, CalendarType.MEETING).
                       optional (
                           _.subject     ("Red Item"),
                           _.description ("Background should be read")
                       )

        val calitem2 = CalendarItem ("5", c2, CalendarType.MEETING).
                       optional (
                           _.subject     ("Green Item"),
                           _.description ("Background should be green"),
                           _.baseCSSClassName ("greenItem")
                       )


        List (calitem1, calitem2)
    }

}
```

And I've confirmed that in the output HTML,  calitem2 has a "cssClass"
attribute set to "greenItem".

```
var calendars = {
    "items": [{"id": "4", "start": 20, "end": 48,
               "weekDay": "3", "startTime": "10:0",              
               "subject": "Red Item", "month": 0, "dayOfMonth": 5,              
               "description": "Background should be read"},
              {"id": "5", "start": 20, "end": 48, "weekDay": "4", 
               "startTime": "10:0", "subject": "Green Item", "month": 0, 
               "dayOfMonth": 6, "description": "Background should be green", 
               "cssClass": "greenItem"}]
};
```

And I also override the original style.css come with CalendarMonthView
and put it under WEB-INF/classes/toserv/calendars/monthview.

I've browse it and make sure that it my modified version, which add
the following "greenItem" CSS classes.

```
.greenItem {
        margin: 1px;

}

.greenItem a {
        margin-left: 1px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #00FF00;
        display: block;

}

.greenItem a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #ff6655;
        display: block;

}

.greenItemHead {
        margin: 1px;

}

.greenItemHead a {
        margin-left: 1px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #00FF00;
        display: block;

}

.greenItemHead a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #ff6655;
        display: block;

}

.greenItemBody {
        margin: 1px;

}

.greenItemBody a {
        margin-left: 1px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #00FF00;
        display: block;

}

.greenItemBody a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #ff6655;
        display: block;
}
```

But when I browse my calendar page, the second CalendarItem is still
in red background, seems the CSS class is not working.

I'm not familiar with JavaScript and JQuery,  so do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it is caused by a bug in Calendar widget module.

So I've file a ticket and created a patch on the tracker.

https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/tickets/563